# terraform remote-exec inline - rds mysql db import error Endpoint terraform-20231021061949136600000001.c5xf4htadaog.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmWlU.png)

Trying to import db.sql database through automated way using terraform remote provisioner
the jump host successfully establish the connection to install mysql client but when trying to connect to the rds instance it gives an error

tried various other ways but it looks when establishes the rds endpoint connection it should not include 3306 port with the endpoint but it always includes the port along with endpoint which gives an error on connection string.. tried other ways to split the port from endpoint but no luck..

`tried to split the rds port 3306 from the rds endpoint DNS name but no luck yet..i need to import the initil.db data to the rds mysql using terraform.

`````
`resource "null_resource" "file_execute" {
  # Establish connection to EC2 machine
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "obbs.sql"
    destination = "/tmp/obbs.sql"
  
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = aws_instance.webserver.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
  }
  # Copy script file from local machine to remote machine
  }

provisioner "remote-exec" {

inline = [
    
    "sudo yum install -y mysql" # Install MySQL client
]
connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = aws_instance.webserver.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
}

}
    
  # Execute script file to remote EC2 webserver machine
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    
    "mysql -h ${aws_db_instance.rds-demo.endpoint} -u${var.db_username} -p${var.db_password} < /tmp/obbs.sql 2>&1",
"
  ]
    connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = aws_instance.webserver.public_ip
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
}
  }`

```
````your text`
`````